# How to define kotlin dsl gradle properties available in settings.gradle.kts and build.gradle.kts?

Tags: gradle, build, kotlin, settings, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multiplatform (kotlin) multiproject gradle project written using the kotlin DSL.  Bear with me.  In settings.gradle.kts, I have two major types of include helpers to deal with alternative project layout, a regular module (module/src) and a mutliplatform module (module/js, module/common, module/jvm).  I then create variables to hold lists of each which I use with these helpers to include everything the way I'd like.

I'd like to be able to reuse this information defined in settings (the lists) in my build.gradle.kts file.

Every time I try to do this the way I would in the build file, I get the same error:

```
val test: List<String> by rootProject.extra(listOf("game", "spine"))
```

or

```
val test: List<String> by extra(listOf("game", "spine"))
```

The error I get is:

```
Line 68: val test: List<String> by rootProject.extra(listOf("game", "spine"))
                                             ^ Expression 'extra' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

My guess is that settings is not extension aware, so even though `this` is of type Project (bc it is the root project) in settings, it doesn't matter and you can't use extra.  The only way I can think of to do this would be to define project properties back in a gradle properties file, but I'm not very keen on that given this doesn't seem like the type of information to keep there.

Is there anything that allows for an extension property to be lazily initialized when buildscript is underway?

Comment: It looks like the only thing really shared by both settings.gradle.kts and build.gradle.kts is gradle instance properties, but the hunt for how to set these seems like a method for setting them has been removed?  I might have found a way to set a single property, so I will investigate this later when I get back to refactoring this part.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit old of a post, but I recently gave an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603853/gradle-kotlin-dsl-access-objects-defined-in-settings-gradle-kts/65377094#65377094).
But will repeat it since I came across this question also....

In **settings.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
// // This works in settings.gradle
// gradle.ext.GLOBAL_VAR = "This is a global value"
// println("settings.gradle ::: " + gradle.GLOBAL_VAR)

// This works in settings.gradle.kts
val settingsValue = "This value was set in settings.gradle.kts"
if (gradle is ExtensionAware) {
    (gradle as ExtensionAware).extra["GLOBAL_VAR"]=settingsValue
    println("settings.gradle.kts ::: " + (gradle as ExtensionAware).extra.get("GLOBAL_VAR"))
}
```

in **build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
// // This works in settings.gradle
// println("build.gradle ::: " + gradle.GLOBAL_VAR)

// This works in settings.gradle.kts
if (gradle is ExtensionAware) println("build.gradle.kts ::: " + (gradle as ExtensionAware).extra.get("GLOBAL_VAR"))
```

- Gradle version 6.6.1