# Gradle Kotlin DSL: access objects defined in settings.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have objects I define in `settings.gradle.kts`. How can I get them from `build.gradle.kts`?

With the groovy DSL, I could put these objects in `gradle.ext`, but the gradle object doesn't seem to support extra in the Kotlin DSL (using Gradle 5.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access extension objects using following code:

```
(gradle as ExtensionAware).extra["myObject"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a bit old of a post, but I just struggled with this for the last 2 weeks.  Hopefully it'll help the next poor developer searching for this answer.  Here is an example of how its done.

In **settings.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
// // This works in settings.gradle
// gradle.ext.GLOBAL_VAR = "This is a global value"
// println("settings.gradle ::: " + gradle.GLOBAL_VAR)

// This works in settings.gradle.kts
val settingsValue = "This value was set in settings.gradle.kts"
if (gradle is ExtensionAware) {
    (gradle as ExtensionAware).extra["GLOBAL_VAR"]=settingsValue
    println("settings.gradle.kts ::: " + (gradle as ExtensionAware).extra.get("GLOBAL_VAR"))
}
```

in **build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
// // This works in settings.gradle
// println("build.gradle ::: " + gradle.GLOBAL_VAR)

// This works in settings.gradle.kts
if (gradle is ExtensionAware) println("build.gradle.kts ::: " + (gradle as ExtensionAware).extra.get("GLOBAL_VAR"))
```

- Gradle version 6.6.1